# Test-path on an array and return values

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm writing a simple PowerShell script to check against two possible locations of a file. After checking the array, if the values return True, it adds a registry entry. If however, the value is false, it returns a message stating not installed.

```
# Verify if directory exists
$reg6432path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\xabx\123"
$reg32path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\xabx\123"

$CheckLoc64 = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\xabx\123.abc"
$CheckLoc32 = "${env:ProgramFiles}\xabx\123.abc"
$CheckLocArray = $CheckLoc32, $CheckLoc64

$PathExists = Test-Path $CheckLocArray
IF ($PathExists -eq $True) {
write-host "xabx is installed"
write-host "Writing registry values"
new-itemProperty -Force -Path $reg6432path -Name "LogonSettingsPath" -Value $CheckLoc64
}
ELSE { new-itemProperty -Force -Path $reg32path -Name "LogonSettingsPath" -Value $CheckLoc32 }

IF ($PathExists -eq $False) {
write-host "xabx Not Installed" }
```

This works, but I was curious if there was any improvements that could help clean this up.

Thanks

Comment: [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a better site for this.

Comment: Also, if the software is installed via an MSI then querying WMI is a simpler solution.

Comment: @gms0ulman Thanks. I'll ask there. didn't know there was one.

Comment: @EBGreen not checking whether the software is installed. The file check is because there is a combo of 32 bit and 64 bit systems, and the install path x86 doesn't exist on 32 bit Windows..

Comment: But if you know the software is installed and you know the architecture then you know exactly where the file is and exactly where to write in the registry.

Comment: @EBGreen Why do extra work? :) With this approach I don't have to make that determination...

Comment: Meh...Just a different opinion of what is work I guess. Two WMI queries seems easier to me that's all

Comment: @JeremiahGowdy It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR (like [_gms0ulman_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039142/gms0ulman) did) but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela No issues here. I didn't know about Code Review until today. So, I went right after gms0ulman recommended to post on code review, but that pesky 40 minute timer prevented it. By then, someone had provided me with an answer. Feel free to close out the request or whatever happens to them. I've copied the resolution and have what I need for now.

Comment: Also, would be kind of nice if the "stack" family had a "transfer question to..." button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are checking an array with test-path, and 1 is true and the other is false, it will return true. You need to test them individual.
I would do something like this.

```
# Verify if directory exists
$reg6432path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\xabx\123"
$reg32path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\xabx\123"

$CheckLoc64 = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\xabx\123.abc"
$CheckLoc32 = "${env:ProgramFiles}\xabx\123.abc"

$Path64 = Test-Path $CheckLoc64
$Path32 = Test-Path $CheckLoc32
IF ($Path64 -eq $True) {
    write-host "xabx is installed"
    write-host "Writing registry values"
    new-itemProperty -Force -Path $reg6432path -Name "LogonSettingsPath" -Value $CheckLoc64
}
elseif ($Path32 -eq $True) {
    new-itemProperty -Force -Path $reg32path -Name "LogonSettingsPath" -Value $CheckLoc32 
} 
else {
    write-host "xabx Not Installed"     
}
```

Or you can just index in the if statement. The [1] tells the if statement to look at the second object in the variable $PathExists.

```
# Verify if directory exists
$reg6432path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\xabx\123"
$reg32path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\xabx\123"

$CheckLoc64 = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\xabx\123.abc"
$CheckLoc32 = "${env:ProgramFiles}\xabx\123.abc"
$CheckLocArray = $CheckLoc32, $CheckLoc64

$PathExists = Test-Path $CheckLocArray
IF ($PathExists[1] -eq $True) {
    write-host "xabx is installed"
    write-host "Writing registry values"
    new-itemProperty -Force -Path $reg6432path -Name "LogonSettingsPath" -Value $CheckLoc64
}
ELSE { new-itemProperty -Force -Path $reg32path -Name "LogonSettingsPath" -Value $CheckLoc32 }

IF ($PathExists -eq $False) {
    write-host "xabx Not Installed" 
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!! The if...esleif...else, I was running into problems figuring that part out.